# Error getting GZIP output stream when using WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to create an API in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 that should return an image of JPEG type.

But I am getting this error: Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error getting GZIP output stream.

So, is it possible to turn off GZIP compression in WSO2 ESB for image/jpeg message types?

> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-23 08:17:09,833] ERROR
>   {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator}
>   -  Error getting GZIP output stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid null character in text to output
>     at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:552)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
>     at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)  at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid null character in text to
>   output    at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.writeCharacters(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl.writeOutput(OMTextImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl.internalSerialize(OMTextImpl.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:143)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid null character in
>   text to output    at
>   com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler$FailingHandler.convertInvalidChar(InvalidCharHandler.java:51)
>     at com.ctc.wstx.sw.XmlWriter.handleInvalidChar(XmlWriter.java:623)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeCharacters(BufferingXmlWriter.java:554)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:460)
>     ... 30 more TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-23 08:17:09,838] ERROR
>   {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} - 
>   Failed to submit the response
>   {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error getting GZIP output stream  at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.handleException(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:552)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
>     at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)  at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid null character in text to output
>     at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid null
>   character in text to output   at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.writeCharacters(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl.writeOutput(OMTextImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl.internalSerialize(OMTextImpl.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:143)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid null character in
>   text to output    at
>   com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler$FailingHandler.convertInvalidChar(InvalidCharHandler.java:51)
>     at com.ctc.wstx.sw.XmlWriter.handleInvalidChar(XmlWriter.java:623)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeCharacters(BufferingXmlWriter.java:554)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:460)
>     ... 30 more TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-23 08:17:09,841] ERROR
>   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - 
>   Content-Encoding:gzip,Content-Type:image/jpeg,Vary:Accept-Encoding,
>   Unexpected error sending message back
>   {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:610)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:269)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
>     at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)  at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:335)     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:529)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
>     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error getting GZIP output stream  at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.handleException(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:552)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
>     ... 20 more Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid null
>   character in text to output   at
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)  at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.util.GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.writeTo(GzipMessageFormatterDecorator.java:66)
>     ... 22 more Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid null
>   character in text to output   at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.writeCharacters(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl.writeOutput(OMTextImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMTextImpl.internalSerialize(OMTextImpl.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeChildren(OMSerializerUtil.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:875)
>     at
>   org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:143)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid null character in
>   text to output    at
>   com.ctc.wstx.api.InvalidCharHandler$FailingHandler.convertInvalidChar(InvalidCharHandler.java:51)
>     at com.ctc.wstx.sw.XmlWriter.handleInvalidChar(XmlWriter.java:623)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeCharacters(BufferingXmlWriter.java:554)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:460)
>     ... 30 more TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-23 08:17:09,844] ERROR
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Could not build
>   full log message: Can not serialize OM Element Envelope
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} TID: [-1234] []
>   [2016-03-23 08:17:09,845] ERROR {API_LOGGER.Photos} -  Could not build
>   full log message: Can not serialize OM Element Envelope
>   {API_LOGGER.Photos} TID: [-1234] [] [2016-03-23 08:17:09,850]  INFO
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To:
>   http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: ,
>   SOAPAction: , MessageID:
>   urn:uuid:e4e1882c-6a04-4c77-b802-0aaf7d5f73cb, Direction: response,
>   MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0,
>   ERROR_MESSAGE =
>   Content-Encoding:gzip,Content-Type:image/jpeg,Vary:Accept-Encoding,
>   Unexpected error sending message back, Envelope: 
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}

Comment: can you share the full error log

Comment: Im not sure if this works but can you remove image/jpeg from catalina-server.xml and check?

Comment: Sorry, but it did not work. I am adding the  log.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error log* the ESB is parsing your image as an application/xml. So perhaps you have made a configuration error in the /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file?

The builder and formatter should be defined as:

```xml
<messageBuilder contentType="image/jpeg" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder" />
<messageFormatter contentType="image/jpeg" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter" />
```

See also: http://sachirajapakse.blogspot.nl/2015/10/send-images-for-rest-api-in-wso2-esb.html

*org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:143) ... 23 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid null character in text to output at (..)